# Preciso saber onde nesse codigo esta o meu erro - MATRIZ EM C

Tags: c, matriz

> Na letra i era pra dar 9,2 mas o resultado que mostra é 9,50.
>
> Como descobrir qual turma tem mais homogeneidade em relação as notas?

```
    float turma1[4][5] ={
                       {8.2,9.2,8.7,6.0,7.0},
                       {3.0,3.4,9.2,9.8,1.9},
                       {4.0,5.2,8.2,7.2,8.7},
                       {10,4.8,8.2,6.7,8.2}
                        };
    float turma2[4][5] ={
                        {6.5,6.5,7.2,7.2,7.8},
                        {9.0,9.2,9.1,8.0,8.2},
                        {3.5,7.9,6.9,9.2,9.2},
                        {8.9,9.2,9.7,10,8.5}
                        };
    int i,j;

 //i) Qual nota foi a mais frequente na turma 2?
    float notaMaisFrequente;

    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        for(j=0; j<5;j++){
            if(turma2[i][j] == turma2[i][j]){
                turma2[i][j] = turma2[i][j]+1;
                notaMaisFrequente = turma2[i][j];
            }
        }
}

printf("Nota mais frequente na Turma 2: %.2f",notaMaisFrequente);
```

Comment: Compilei aqui e apareceu: O aluno 0 da Turma 2 teve a maior media.                                                                                       
Nota mais frequente na Turma 2: 9.50

Comment: estou analisando seu código, há erro de lógica na condição: if(turma2[i][j] == turma2[i][j]) , só estou pensando um jeito de uma variavel receber qual vetor mais se repete

Comment: Meu amigo, terei que sair logo, por isso tento responder sua pergunta até amanha, caso eu nao consiga, oferecerei uma recompensa para alguém da comunidade ajudar!

Comment: Okay, mesmo assim fico agradecida por tentar me ajudar

Comment: O erro, como já foi falado, está no `if(turma2[i][j] == turma2[i][j])`, o que você tem que fazer é salvar todos os números que saíram e, caso o número já tenha saído uma vez, você tem que adicionar 1 no número de vezes que ele saiu...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando força bruta, daria para resolver a letra (i) assim:

```
//i) Qual nota foi a mais frequente na turma 2?
    float notaMaisFrequente = 0;
    int quantidade = 0;

    int q = 0;
    int a, b;

   for(i=0;i<4;i++){
      for(j=0; j<5;j++){
         for(a = 0; a < 4; a++){
            for(b = 0; b < 5; b++){
               if(turma2[i][j] == turma2[a][b]){
                  q++;
               }
            }
         }
         if(q > quantidade){
            quantidade = q;
            notaMaisFrequente = turma2[i][j];
         }
         q = 0;
      }
   }

printf("Nota mais frequente na Turma 2: %.2f",notaMaisFrequente);
```

Caso seja necessário um algoritmo mais eficiente, **eu imagino** que seria inevitavelmente necessária uma estrutura de dados com alocação dinâmica de memória, para guardar as diferentes notas e a quantidade de vezes que cada uma se repete. Isso pode ficar bem trabalhoso.

Comment: Muito obrigada, ajudou bastante :D

Answer (score 0):

```
if(turma2[i][j] == turma2[i][j]){ // Se 8,5 é igual a 8,5
    turma2[i][j] = turma2[i][j]+1; // Soma 8,5+1 e sobrepõem o valor de turma2[i][j]
    notaMaisFrequente = turma2[i][j]; // notaMaisFrequente = 9,5
```

O resultado é 9,5 porque nessa parte do código vc apenas verifica se um número é igual ele mesmo, então esse if sempre vai ser verdadeiro. Sendo assim o valor de notaMaisFrequente será o ultimo valor de turma2 somado 1.

Comment: @bbyink se quiser uma sugestão de como resolver seu problema segue o link do código: https://pastebin.com/SMWyuDvW

Comment: Ah, vdd... não tinha chegado a esse raciocinio :D Obrigada